# Xtext optional ordering with comma

Tags: xtext

I have a DSL that looks like JSON and I need to support optional ordering of the elements.  For example:

```
{
    'id': 'someid',
    'position' : 'someposition',
    'operand' : 'someoperand'
}
```

In order to support any ordering of 'id', 'position', and 'operand' tokens with valid commas, I had to do something like this:

```
Block returns Block:
    {Block}
    '{'
        members+=BlockMember (',' members+=BlockMember)*
    '}'
;

BlockMember returns BlockMember:
    blockId=BlockId | position=BlockPosition | operand=Operand
;
```

The problem is that each element (id, position, operand) is both mandatory as well as only once.  With this grammar, I have some issues:

1. You can define the elements more than once (which also screws up LSP
   content assist later).
2. I can't enforce the mandatory requirement.
3. It creates an inferred EMF model where a Block has a 'members' collection instead of well defined properties.  This means later to parse a Block, I have to iterate the member.
4. Because it needs to be well-formed JSON, the last property cannot have a comma

I know I can do this if I enforce a specific order and look for the comma.  What I would like to do however is have the optional ordering with commas between (except for last) without introducing a 'members' that creates the issues listed above.

Is there a technique to do this?

Comment: Did you have a look at the concept op unordered groups

Comment: Or did you think of doing stuff in grammar AND validation

Comment: I am not sure the best way to go here.  Unordered groups looks good (https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/301_grammarlanguage.html#unordered-groups), but not sure about how to get the comma between everything but not last.

Comment: yes thus you should go with validation

Comment: So plan is to use unordered group then.  Would you recommend leaving the comma out of the grammar and only looking for it in validator?  Or the other way?

Comment: no i would keep the grammar as you have it and then add a validation and adapt content assist to avoid duplicates